# Include and remove $.ajax properties dynamically

Tags: jquery, ajax, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

There's any way to edit an $.ajax function, to include the proprierty "data", when she's receive any value, and remove her, when there's not? I mean, dynamically? e.g.:

When there's a value to the variable:

```
var parametro = "{id: "1"}";

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: parametro ,
            async: async,
    ...
```

When there's no variable, or, no value to her:

```
var parametro = "";

     $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: async,
    ...
```

So, my idea is something like that:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            if(parametro)
            {
               data: parametro,
            },           
            async: async,
    ...
```

I tried other stuff like:

```
data: undefined
data: ""
data: null
```

But nothing seems to work. The only way to send an empty "data" property, it is to remove it completely. Thus, in addition to creating two different functions, one with a "data" property, and another without her, there's any soloution?

Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: If your main language is Portuguese, it would be better if you posted this on [StackOverflow em Portugues](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Sorry, i tried to translate the question.

Comment: check your if condition outside of an ajax call

Comment: You could just send an empty data object var `parametro = {};` and always have  `data: parametro`

Answer (score 1):

Because both of them are objects, you can use `jQuery.extend()` to extend the options object.

Like this:

```
var parametro = {
        id: "1"
    };

var defaults = {
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: async,
        ...
    };

var options = $.extend(defaults, parametro);

$.ajax(options);
```

Link:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know
I would suggest put the if condition outside of `$.ajax` such as

```
if(parametro){
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: parametro ,
        async: async,
        ...
        });
}else{
   $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        async: async,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
if(parametro)
   {
           $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: parametro,           
            async: false,
           });
}
```

if no data then no needs to do ajax call, I think.